# What should I do to use local development?

Tags: github, jekyll

When I clone the project from https://github.com/daattali/beautiful-jekyll.git on my computer, I use **jekyll serve** to start the project, but it will some error, what should I do if I want to  Local development using jekyll?

the error is:

```
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      jekyll-watch (~> 1.1)
      rouge (< 3, >= 1.7)
      rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.4, ~> 0.9)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9.7, ~> 0.9)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:313:in `check_for_activated_spec!': You have already activated public_suffix 3.0.1, but your Gemfile requires public_suffix 2.0.5. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `block in setup'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/forwardable.rb:229:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/forwardable.rb:229:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:26:in `map'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-`enter code here`1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:26:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.6.2/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:50:in `require_from_bundler'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.6.2/exe/jekyll:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: "Some error" isn't very helpful. Please [edit] your question and add the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my question.
First: you should add the code to your Gemfile file.
the code is

```
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw]
```

Then: you use `bundle exec jekyll serve` to start. After that you can use local development.